# Check self adjointness of element

Tags: spectral-theory, functional-calculus

Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$ algebra, $u$ an unitary element such that $\sigma(u)\neq\mathbb{T}$ (the spectrum). Consider the usual complex $\log$ function (with the usual branch). Under these circunstances, $\log \in C(\sigma(u))$, so that $\log(u)$ "makes sense". Now let $a:=\frac{\log(u)}{i}$, and prove that it is self adjoint.

To do this it suffices to check that $[\log(u)]^*=-\log(u)$, but I am little confused on how to compute $[\log(u)]^*$. Can someone help me explain why is this true? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by  "the usual branch"?  Normally people understand it as being defined on $\mathbb C$ minus the negative reals.  However, if $-1$ is in $\sigma(u)$, you don't get a continuous function defined on the whole $\sigma(u)$.

Comment: Hi @Ruy, well thinking about it maybe we should define $\log$ on the complex plane except for a curve that connects $0$ and $\infty$, such that it does not intersect $\sigma(u)$. Hence we have a continous function on the spectrum. But what is the correct way to think of $[\log(u)]^*$?

Comment: Ok, that is an important 1st step.  Now here are some questions for you: 1) what is the range of $\log/i$ defined on the spectrum? 2) What does the spectral mapping theorem say?  3) What is the spectrum of $\log(u)/i$ ?

Comment: Dear@Ruy I finally got some time to think about the problem again. To answer your questions: 1) The range is the spectrum of $\log(u)/i$ (using SMT), right? About the spectrum of $\log(u)/i$ I still have my doubts. But I see how we want it to be in the reals.. Why is this the case?

Comment: The SMT says that the spectrum of $f(u)$ is $f(\sigma(u))$.  So all you have to do is figure out what is this.  You already know what is $\sigma(u)$: a subset of the circle.

Comment: Dear @Ruy thank you for the comment. And we know the spectrum is striclty contained in the unit circle since $u$ is unitary. But $log(z)/i=(|z| + i\arg(z))/i$ which is not neccesarily real given the information that we have... Sorry if this is too elementary

Comment: Your formula for $log$ is incorrect!

Comment: Omg. Of course, I missed the $\log |z|$, which is 0. Thank you so much @Ruy.